# How to get response from python to php?

Tags: php, python

Php never get response If I use sleep for 5 minutes or more in python. Using sleep around 2 minutes , its working, I do not know what is happening, where is the problem?

**Sample Code**

**uploadfile_database.php:**

```
<?php
    $file_id=1; 
    $response=exec('python /home/xyz/test.py '.$file_id);

    echo $response;

?>
```

**test.py**

```
  import os, json
  import sys

   sleep(300)
   #sleep(420)
   print "hello"
```

Comment: You may take advantage of the underlying OS services, e.g., use pipes (to connect _stdout_ of one component to the _stdin_ on the next component):
`0.ajax | 1.php | 2.py`

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

`exec` does not work as you're expecting. To get the output from of your python script you need to pass an output parameter to [exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php).

Ex.

```
$output = array();
$exit_code = exec('python /home/xyz/test.py '.$file_id, &$output);
```

You could also just use [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) which would work as you're expecting

Comment: See my updated question . If you run my sample code php and python. Php never get response from python,Its working if we use sleep  less than 2 minutes in python.I do not know what is the problem.any help?